# Mongoexport blank fields to csv

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I'm exporting a series of mongo collections to csv files. I'm explicitly setting the field names to export by calling a dictionary, if a field does not exist in a given document, I would still like to create an empty field in the csv column

I'm currently getting these errors in my console: 
`too many positional arguments: ['pfrm_uid', 'mark']]`

This occurs for all collections. I find it most strange that there are 2 closing brackets in the error.

```
for item_name in self.exported_fields_Dict.keys():

    fields_to_export = self.exported_fields_Dict[item_name]
    self.item_count_dict[item_name] = self.item_count_dict[item_name] + 1

    os.system("mongoexport --host localhost 
                           --collection {0} 
                           --db scrapy-mongodb-test 
                           --type=csv 
                           --out {1}.csv
                           --fields {2}".format(
                                  item_name,
                                  item_name,
                                  fields_to_export))
```

Below is the dictionary I pulling the collection name and field names from

```
// collection name : fields_to_export
exported_fields_Dict = {
       'ent_pfrm': ['pfrm_uid', 'mark'],
       'ent_indv': ['indv_uid', 'fName', 'lName', 'gender', 'DOB'],
       'ent_meet': ['meet_uid', 'name', 'start_date', 'end_date']
    }
```

Any tips / suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoexport script expects comma separated fields as a string for the [fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-fields) argument.

You can test and see that this is not such a string:

```
> print(exported_fields_Dict['ent_pfrm'])
['pfrm_uid', 'mark']
```

you can either store strings as your dict values, e.g. `"pfrm_uid, mark"` or substitute the last argument inside the format method with

```
",".join( fields_to_export[item_name] )
```

this prints what you want: `pfrm_uid,mark`